# Gridbag layout not aligning properly

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout, miglayout

I'm working on a solitaire game with java and swing, and I'm experiencing an anoying issue. I have a panel for the game with a miglayout that seems to work fine, but inside of it there are 7 panels more with the piles of the cards, each of them has a gridbaglayout but as you can see in the next image, the piles aren't aligned correctly:

[image: The issue in cuestion]

The main panel is grey and the panels with the cards are in green.

The code were the subpanels are created is here:
https://github.com/ccokee/Solitarios/blob/master/src/pClasico.java#L166

And the code of the sub panels is here:
https://github.com/ccokee/Solitarios/blob/master/src/pMontonC.java#L33

Can someone help me to solve this? I've been messing around with this for a long run but no success :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the `GridBagLayout` will center the components vertically (and horizontally) in the panel unless one of the components has a `weighty` value not equal to 0.

This will give the extra space of the panel to that component. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information.

However, I would suggest a better solution is to use a vertical BoxLayout and then you can just add "glue" to the end to take up the extra space.

Something like:

```
Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
box.add( card1 );
box.add( card2 );
...
box.add( Box.createVerticalGlue() );
```

Another option might be to use the [Overlap Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/overlap-layout/). This layout manager allows you to position components on top of one another.

Comment: Adding a empty label with weight at the end of the pile did the trick, thanks camickr.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the issue in the code.

In the class `pClassico.java`, try to change the line 296 :

`interior.add(MontonesJuego[i], "cell " + (i+4) + " 3");`

with this one :

`interior.add(MontonesJuego[i], "cell " + (i+5) + " 3");`

Here is what I have on my environment :
[image: Solitarios with aligned piles.]

Hope it will help !

Comment: Sorry, but I applied the weighty solution given and updated the repo so you were working with the fixed version.